# JQuery accessing PHP generated content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have

```
<?php 
   include('print.php') 
?>
```

That echoes html code inside my document, and after I load it I can't access the divs by id with jQuery

```
$("#"+divId)
```

It doesn't work even from chrome's console.
I can access them with plain javascript

```
 document.getElementById(divId)
```

If I hardcode the divs I can access them via jQuery.
Can anyone explain me why php-generated code is not accessible via jQuery?

Comment: show us your code. HTML, PHP and Javascript code.

Comment: inspect element and post the html here

Comment: Are you including Jquery Library

Comment: php is rendered on the server, before the client even loads. so there is an error with your code, it can't be related to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it proved to be a stuipid distraction, The fact that the content was dynamically generated on the server side was totally incidental. One of the divs contained a dot instead of a dash in the id ('#1.0'), so jquery was interpreting it as '#[id].[class]'

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$('#' + divId)` inside your document load. It does not work from chrome's console because variable `divId` does not exist.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
   var divId = Whatever your Div ID is;
   var div = $('#' + divId);
});
```